# How to Express the Probabilities Associated with a Third Variable in a Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, bayesian-network

Suppose I have an observation $Y_t$ that is conditionally dependent on $X_t$. (More specifically, Y is a series of observations emitted by an underlying hidden Markov state sequence X.)

I can describe the distribution of $p(Y_t)$ as

$$\sum_{x_t} p(Y_t|X_t)p(X_t),$$

that is to say, the sum of the emission probabilities for all possible hidden states.

My question is, suppose I also have a third variable Z. Can I express $p(Y_t|z)$ as:

$$\sum_{x_t} p(Y_t|X_t)p(X_t|z)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes – generally one would have to conditionalize the entire expression,

$$
p(Y_t|z)=\sum_{x_t} p(Y_t|X_t,z)p(X_t|z)\;,
$$

but as you rightly pointed out in a comment, in this case $Y_t$ depends only on $X_t$, so $p(Y_t|X_t,z)=p(Y_t|X_t)$ and the sum reduces to your sum,

$$
p(Y_t|z)=\sum_{x_t} p(Y_t|X_t)p(X_t|z)\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you. What I don't quite understand about this is the following. Since we are dealing with a HMM, we know observation $Y_t$ is dependent on $X_t$. So if we *know* the value for a particular $X_t$, wouldn't $Y_t$ then be independent of Z? So isn't it safe to say $$p(Y_t|X_t, z) = p(Y_t|X_t)$$

if we know X?

Thanks for your kind help :)

Comment: @davec: Sorry, I hadn't read the question carefully enough -- you're right, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: OK that clears up the last of my confusion, so accepted! :)